# Smartest way to add KL Divergence into (Variational) Auto Encoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I have an **Auto Encoder model** with *multiple outputs* and *weightening* which a want to enrich **into a Variational Auto Encoder**.
I followed this: https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/ official keras tutorial.

But if a manually adapt the train_step function I lose the majority of my original implementation details:

1. I got two weighted optimization goals: *re-construction (decoder)* and *classification (softmax)*
2. *accuracy metrics* for the classification
3. the original fit method also takes care of the *validation data and corresponding metrics*

Adding the suggested sampling layer according to the keras link is no problem, but to correctly implement the **Kullback-Leibler-Loss** as it depends on the additional parameters **z_mu** and **z_log_var** which is not supported by standard Keras losses.

I search for some workarounds to solve this issue but none of them was succesfull:

1. **re-writing the train_step:** its hard to fully re-implement all details (
   weightening, multiple losses with different inputs -> decoder: data, classifier: labels etc)
2. **adding a psyeudo layer to the ecoder that calculates the loss:** https://tiao.io/post/tutorial-on-variational-autoencoders-with-a-concise-keras-implementation/ like here. But here is the problem that the add loss function does not specify to which key and how *KL-Loss is added to the model's total loss*
3. **Adding everything as global/top-level** element to make the z_mu, z_log_var accessible for the loss calculation like here: https://www.machinecurve.com/index.php/2019/12/30/how-to-create-a-variational-autoencoder-with-keras/. This is the approach I like the least as my current architecture is parametrized to be able to e.g. perform hyperopt tuning

I was not able to find a pleasing solution to this problem, as VAE's are more and more popular I  am surprised by the phenomenon that there is no extended tutorial about this especially when dealing with multiple in- and outputs. Or I am just unable to find the right answers through my query.

Any opinions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of re-designs I and bug-ticket tracing I found this recent example:
[here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#the_model_class)

The VAE examples can be found at the very *bottom of the post*.

1. Solution: **write your own train_step:** cleanest but also hardest solution depending how complex your loss calculation is.
2. Solution: u**se a functional approach the access the necessary variables and add the loss with .add_loss:** not very clean but straight to implement (you will lose an additional loss tracker for the KL-loss)

To achieve my weighting I weighted the KL loss before I added it via `.add_loss` according to the weight of my decoder loss.

Note: The first solution I tested was to define a custom loss function for the mse+kl loss and added it into my functional designed model - this works if one turns of the **tf eager eval off**. But be careful this really *slows down your network* and you will *lose the ability to monitor your training via tensorboard* if you don't have admin rights for your nvidia gpu (profile_batch=0 does not turn off profiling if eager mode is switched off, therefore you ran into INSUFFICENT_PRIVILEDGES Errors with the CUPTI driver)